# Material Slider OnSliderTouchListener's methods can only be called from within the same library group

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

Implementing BaseOnSliderTouchListener's `onStartTrackingTouch` and `onStopTrackingTouch` ([documentation](https://material.io/components/sliders/android#using-sliders)) give the lint the following error message :

> Error: BaseOnSliderTouchListener.onStartTrackingTouch can only be called from within the same library group (referenced groupId=com.google.android.material from groupId=your-group-id) [RestrictedApi]

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. The workaround with `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` works.

The root cause is that the `BaseOnSliderTouchListener` class has a library restricted scope and the methods exposed there are not overridden in `OnSliderTouchListener`.

The issue is tracked in the material-components library here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2493

It has been fixed in the 1.6.0-alpha02 release of material-components.

Answer (score 6):

Temporary solution:

Add `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` annotation.

Example:

```
    slider.addOnSliderTouchListener(object : Slider.OnSliderTouchListener {
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(slider: Slider) {
             [...]
        }

        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(slider: Slider) {
          [...]
        }
    })
```